# PHP parse_url not working for current URL

Tags: php, parsing

It works

```
$url = parse_url('http://yabadaba.com/brand#asos');
echo $url['fragment'];
```

But it doesn't work

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $url['fragment'];
```

What is wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

That is because the parameter preceded by `#` will not reach the server-side script. You can get it only by Javascript.

#### Why does it work on the first case ?

- That is because you are hard-coding it in the `parse_url` function.

Comment: I can do it with query string but hashtag looks modern. So according to you, I'll need to pass javascript to php. Which will not work if javascript is disabled.

Comment: @Waqas The modern part of hashtag goes together with dynamically loading the content via Ajax ... you can't really do one without the other :)

Comment: If you are looking to parse the variables with PHP , you need to pass the parameters in the _usual_ way you do it. Btw I don't see any _moderness_ in the `#` btw :)